# pygresql copy_from gives a relation does not exist error

Tags: python, pygresql

I have the following code

```
pg_con = conns.con_to_pg()
cur = pg_con.cursor()

with open('up_md.csv', 'r') as f:
    next(f)  # Skip the header row.
    tbl = 'bidba.upmeta'
    cur.copy_from(f, tbl, 'csv', sep=',')

pg_con.commit()
```

The schema and table `bidba.upmeta` exist in my postgres db.
No matter what I do, I get the message: `relation "bidba.upmeta" does not exist` error.

I tried writing it with single quotes, double quotes, without quotes.
Nothing helps. What am I missing? Is there an issue with the `copy_from` method?

Answer (score 6):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/PyGreSQL/PyGreSQL/issues/47) and will be fixed in the next version of PyGreSQL.

As a workaround, you can pass `tbl = 'upmeta'`. This should work if your `bidba` schema is in the search path. Otherwise, you can put it into the search path for the current session with `SET search_path TO bidba, public` before calling `copy_from`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I added:  cur.execute('SET search_path TO bidba, public'),  but still getting same error

Comment: Did you pass tbl = 'upmeta' (i.e. without a dot)? The table name casing matters as well. If it has been created as "Upmeta" or "UpMeta" it will now work.

Comment: It works now. I passed only the table name without the schema. Thanks so much !